# back fill NA values in panel data set

Tags: r, panel, na, fill

I want to know how I can backfill NA values in panel data set.

data set

```
date    firms   return
1999      A      NA
2000      A      5
2001      A      NA
1999      B      9
2000      B      NA
2001      B      10
```

expected out come

```
date    firms   return
1999      A      5
2000      A      5
2001      A      NA
1999      B      9
2000      B      10
2001      B      10
```

I use this formula to fill NA values with previous value in panel data set

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1<-df %>% group_by(firms) %>% fill(return)
```

Is there any easy way like this by which I can fill NA values with next value in a panel data set.

Comment: Have a look at the na.locf function from the zoo package

Comment: I know that but is it for panel data setting ?

Comment: What do you think is different or special about a panel data setting? You can use `fill` or `zoo::na.locf`. Have a look at the help page. In `fill` you can set `direction = "up"` instead of the default `direction = "down"`. Always a good place to start is a help page, see `?fill`

Comment: look at the example expected outcome. 2001      A      NA value is not filled by 9 because of panel data sets. where I put direction = "up". Can you write full code for me please.

Comment: thank you so much. I am getting the same result. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(firms) %>% fill(return, .direction="up")
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   firms [2]
   date firms return
  <int> <fct>  <int>
1  1999 A          5
2  2000 A          5
3  2001 A         NA
4  1999 B          9
5  2000 B         10
6  2001 B         10
```

Comment: thank you so much. but it is not working. r is not showing any error. Taking code nicely but output remains same.

Comment: Try running just `head(df %>% group_by(firms) %>% fill(return, .direction="up"),20)` without assigning it. What do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The data frame is not changing again. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Can you show your actual current df, the code you're using, and the result, as they are in the terminal?

Comment: Sorry, It is working. What happens that they are not considering cells as a NA values. Now it is ok.